# Commerce V7 - Is there any way to separate Addresses?

Tags: e-commerce, websphere-commerce, wcs

I have been researching 'SharedShippingBillingPage' feature in AuroraStorefrontAssetStore but I haven't got much, IBM's info center is quiet about it.

Is there any link that can be useful in this regard?

I checked in db that this feature is enabled by default but I don't want to use it, I want to disable it. Our requirement is to have separate billing and shipping addresses in our application.

How to do it? Does IBM provide any way to get separate billing and shipping addresses from user and save them?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Store Management tool and see if this feature is available to toggle there - it may depend on your installation FP version.

If not (not all features are exposed), then have a look at a database level. See this [related tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.management-center_customization.doc/tutorial/ttf_tutorialcontacttooltip.htm) that explains a little about the involved tables.

As a quick check, see what this gets you:

```
select * from dmemspotdef d inner join emspot e on e.emspot_id=d.emspot_id where e.emspot_id in (select emspot_id from emspot where name like 'SharedShippingBillingPage');
```

And to disable (for all stores):

```
update dmemspotdef set content = 'false' where emspot_id IN (select emspot_id from emspot where name = 'SharedShippingBillingPage');
```

Comment: I have disabled it from Db but it is not working.As I already mentioned in OP that " Our requirement is to have separate billing and shipping addresses in our application." Could you please suggest how to do it?

Comment: Have you cleared cached pages, updated registries or restarted? The instructions above will disable the feature. 
Is this the only thing you want? I.e. is the disabling not working or is it working but you don't get the effect you want?

Comment: I did all of that,after restart feature gets disabled as I put some checks to see if the change would work,so feature got disabled & system got it but it is not impacting the creation and persistence of addresses.Shipping and Billing addresses didn't get separated,so yes disabling is working but I don't get the effect I want.& I am actually not much concerned about this feature,I just want to separate the addresses so I was searching for ways to do it & I found this feature & thought it might be messing so disabled it.Would you please help me in separating addresses, Is there any way to do it?

Comment: "Shipping and Billing addresses didn't get separated": what do you mean by this? Are you seeing 2 separate address forms, complete them differently and then what? Like you end up with 1 address in the database?

Comment: Exactly, If I add shipping address, billing address section also gets updated with the same data and vice versa and each time a new record added , marking previous one as 'Temporary', and temporary addresses don't come in 'person' REST service and cannot be updated so user gets stuck and always have one address that is recently updated either shipping or billing.